# Dart How to compare UIDs of two Lists and Generate third List in Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, firebase, dart

I have two lists coming from Firebase, List1 contains all the information of users along with their UIDs.
List2 Contains only UIDs of some Users (not all).

I want to get all the details of Users of List2 from List1 by comparing their UIDs

How it would be done?

**List1 Contains:**
uid
Name
Email
Age
Etc

**List2 Contains:**
uid (UIDs of users which is also in List 1)

Comment: 1. Iterate over List1 and create a `Map` of UIDs to details. 2. Iterate over List2 and lookup each UID in the `Map` to get the corresponding details.

Answer (score 1):

@jamesdlin explained the logic, but I want to show this with an example:

```
List list1 = [{'name': 'David', 'uid': '1', 'email': 'David@david.com'},
               {'name': 'Michael', 'uid': '2', 'email': 'Michael@michael.com'},
               {'name': 'Sam', 'uid': '3', 'email': 'SeriousSam@sam.com'},
               {'name': 'Oguz', 'uid': '5', 'email': 'oguz@codeoguz.xyz'},
               {'name': 'Esmail', 'uid': '4', 'email': 'Esmail@esmail.com'}];
List list2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
List list3 = [];

void main() {
  //Loop through list 1
  for(Map item in list1){
    //Loop through list2 for every element in list1
    for(String idUser in list2){
      //If the id mathches add item from list1 to list3
      if(idUser == item['uid']){
        list3.add(item);
      }
    }
  }
  print(list3);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being a noob...
I have a list of List<UserModel> and the second list is List<RequestModel>, it is not working with the given solution...

The Error: The type 'List<UserModel>' used in the 'for' loop must implement 'Iterable' with a type argument that can be assigned to 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.

Comment: By The Way! Thanks for your reply... it was good but didn't solve my problem... 
I found the solution for now... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this. I was having two lists—`List<UserModel>` and `List<RequestModle>`, respectively.

In the below code, `homeCtrlr.allUsers` is a complete list of all Users, and `homeCtrlr.requests` is a list of all UIDs of users:

```
final List<UserModel> userDetails = [];

for (var i = 0; i < homeCtrlr.requests!.length; i++) {
  for (var j = i; j < homeCtrlr.allUsers!.length; j++) {
    if (homeCtrlr.requests![i].requestBy ==
        homeCtrlr.allUsers![j].uid) {
      userDetails.add(homeCtrlr.allUsers![j]);
    }
  }
}
```